# Excel GETPIVOTDATA formula how to drag across and change dates automatically?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I need to create a formula that takes data from pivot table and the data is automatically update when I drag the formula across in my table (picture 2).

My pivot table looks as below:

[image: Pivot Table]

My table is as below:

[image: Table]

My `GETPIVOTDATA` formula is as below:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Is it valid?",'Pivot Tables from Data 1'!$A$3,"SITE","London","Is it valid?",Yes","Credit Week",247)
```

I tried to amend my formula and add `247+COLUMN()-2)` but it doesn't work. I think the problem is the format of date in pivot table but I'm unable to change it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the 247? (I can't offer a solution, just trying to understand this formula)

Comment: It seems that formula picks 03-Sep as 247 (maybe number of days already this year?) I'm unsure why it does pick this way.

Comment: I created this formula by using the = sign and then selected cell C7 in my pivot table.

Comment: @Tobi `247` is equivalent to the date `03-Sep-1900`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it replaces the last argument (247 aka days in year thus far) with a formula to calculate the same:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Is it valid?",'Pivot Tables from Data 1'!$A$3,"SITE","London","Is it valid?",Yes","Credit Week",A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0)+1)
```

Replace A1 with whatever cell the 3-Sep-18 is in and copy to the right.

Comment: Brilliant, it works perfectly! Thanks very much extensionhelp!

Comment: Hello @extensionhelp I believe you will be able to help me again. I got a similar query -  Can you please have a look into this link? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580497/excel-getpivotdata-formula-how-to-drag-the-formula-across-and-change-dates-aut) Thanks in advance