# Excel GETPIVOTDATA formula - how to drag the formula across and change dates automatically?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I need to create a formula that takes data from pivot table and the data is automatically update when I drag the formula across in my table (picture 2).

My pivot table looks as below:

[image]

My table is as below:

[image]

My `GETPIVOTDATA` formula is as below:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Is it valid?",'Overall by Site-2'!$A$8,"Is it valid?","Valid","Week commencing",DATE(2019,1,14))
```

I tried to add `"Week commencing",BK8-DATE(YEAR(BK8),1,0)+1)` to my code but it doesn't pick any data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `GETPIVOTDATA`, just use either `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` formulas:

```
=VLOOKUP(BK8,'Overall by Site-2'!$A:$C,3,0)
```

or

```
=INDEX('Overall by Site-2'!$C:$C,MATCH(BK8,'Overall by Site-2'!$A:$A,0))
```

I personally prefer to use `INDEX/MATCH` as it is much faster method and also much more efficient, especially if you work with large data sets.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks!